# How do you directly access the Omniauth facebook image url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Using Omniauth version 1.0.2, currently when I call `env["omniauth.auth"]["info"]["image"]` to get the image for the current user I get a URL:
`http://graph.facebook.com/100002739564577/picture?type=square`
This redirects to the actual jpeg url which is what I want:
`http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/532749_100003719364175_332972681_a.jpg`

Is it possible to get the jpeg url directly in rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to if you want to display the image.
This works:
`<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/100002739564577/picture?type=square" />`

If you must however, try this:

```
url = URI.parse('http://graph.facebook.com/100002739564577/picture?type=square')
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(url)
res['location'] #returns the image URL
```